# Xquery, How to add an attribute to an XML element with out using a function

Tags: xml, xquery

Here's the starting XML:

```
<sec sec-type="bodytext">
  <title>Largest Cities (Population)</title>
  <list list-type="bullet">
    <list-item>
      <p> Billings (103,994)</p>
    </list-item>
    <list-item>
      <p> Missoula (57,053)</p>
    </list-item>
  </list>
</sec>
```

I want to add this attribute list-content="largest_cities" to element "list".
Here is the output I want:

```
<sec sec-type="bodytext">
  <title>Largest Cities (Population)</title>
  <list list-type="bullet" list-content="largest_cities">
    <list-item>
      <p> Billings (103,994)</p>
    </list-item>
    <list-item>
      <p> Missoula (57,053)</p>
    </list-item>
  </list>
</sec>
```

Here is my Xquery so far:

```
declare variable $current_file as xs:string external;
for $s in doc($current_file)//sec[@sec-type="bodytext"]/list
for $r in doc($current_file)//sec[@sec-type="bodytext"]
where starts-with($r/title,'Ten Largest Cities')
return rename node $s as list[@list-content="largest_cities", 
                             @list-content="largest_cities"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As you already indicated, you rather want to add a node instead of renaming it. Maybe you can answer your own question by using the "insert" expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
for $sec in doc($current_file)//sec
where $sec/@sec-type eq "bodytext" and
      starts-with($sec/title,'Largest Cities')
return
  insert node
    attribute list-content { "largest_cities" }
  into
    $sec/list
```